# Excluding all locations in AdWords except US

Tags: google-ads, geotargeting, country-specific

Is there a way to exclude all locations in AdWords **except** the US?

I'm not sure if the only way to do this is the manually add countries that aren't US (I know the limit is 1,000. I'm also aware that you can target your ads).

Comment: What are you trying to exclude these locations from in AdWords?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller although my locations are targeted to US, I still pull in traffic from Asian / African regions I'd like to exclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geo targeting in AdWords generally includes not just people that are actually *in* your targeted location but also people that:

- Search for your targeted location
- View pages in your targeted location

If you target to the United States, you may end up advertising to people that view US websites from out of the country.

This behavior of targeting can be changed to restrict targeting to only people who are *in* the targeted location.   To do so, make sure the advanced targeting setting of "People in, searching for, or viewing pages about my targeted location" is disabled.